# Can't compile extern C with declspec

Tags: c++, windows, dll, extern, declspec

Hello I don't know why I can't compile this code ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
   extern "C"
   {
      __declspec(dllexport) unsigned long NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I get this error :

> C:\Users\Axel\Desktop\TestPerso\main.cpp|9|error: expected unqualified-id >before string constant|

I'm running on a PC with an Intel Hd chipset and Nvidia graphical card 920M with Windows 10 ont it.

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: You cannot export local variables, they don't have a stable address and highly unpredictable lifetime.  Consider to keep the declaration outside of the function body so it becomes a global variable.

Comment: Thanks compiling now